# Can I change font based on predicted width

Tags: dimension-expressions

Is it possible to define a macro that changes font based on width that a box "would be"?

I'd like to define a LaTeX macro that does something like:

```
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1] {
    \if\latexMagicWidthOf{\labelfont #1}>2em
        {\labelfont #1}
    \else
        {\condensedlabelfont #1}
    \fi
}
```

In other words, if #1 would be wider than 2em in labelfont, use condensedlabelfont instead.

I think I could implement \latexMagicWidthOf with a \newbox and \wd\labelbox, but I'm stuck on comparing dimensions for anything but equality.

Comment: hint: `\ifdim` for comparing sizes

Comment: note your suggested macro would add extra white space as you have not used `%` at ends of lines.  why not `{\labelfont\resizebox{2em}{!}{#1}}` which will set the text to 2em width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1] {%%%%%
    \sbox\mybox{\labelfont #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\mybox <2em % do you want to set the font here? 2em is in whatever the current font is
        \usebox{\mybox}%%%%
    \else
        {\condensedlabelfont #1}%%%%
    \fi
}
```

But perhaps simpler would be

```
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1] {{\labelfont\resizebox{2em}{!}{#1}}}
```

which will set the text 2em wide in the labelfont.